# R YieldCurve Nelson Siegel fitting

Tags: r, yield, curve

I have been able to get Nelson-Siegel parameters but I would like to use those parameters to fit multiple daily maturities in xts object. My example parameter data looks like:

```
             beta_0    beta_1    beta_2    lambda
2016-05-09 1.242251 -1.587428 -2.877986 0.3260436
2016-05-10 1.310086 -1.698266 -2.771920 0.2988770
2016-05-11 1.305433 -1.709373 -2.741923 0.2988770
2016-05-12 1.296316 -1.647487 -2.917838 0.3260436
2016-05-13 1.296014 -1.703771 -2.716187 0.2988770
```

and maturity data:

```
           DBR 4 1/4 07/04/17 OBL 0 1/2 10/13/17 DBR 4 01/04/18 OBL 0 1/2 02/23/18 OBL 0 1/4 04/13/18
2016-05-09           1.153425           1.430137       1.657534           1.794521           1.928767
2016-05-10           1.150685           1.427397       1.654795           1.791781           1.926027
2016-05-11           1.147945           1.424658       1.652055           1.789041           1.923288
2016-05-12           1.145205           1.421918       1.649315           1.786301           1.920548
2016-05-13           1.142466           1.419178       1.646575           1.783562           1.917808
```

Package YieldCurve has a nice function `NSrates` which will calculate Nelson-Siegel yields given the parameters and maturities, but I have only gotten to point where it does so for 1 row at the time.

```
> NSrates(para[1,], matu[1,])
           X1.15342465753425 X1.43013698630137 X1.65753424657534 X1.79452054794521 X1.92876712328767
2016-05-09        -0.5036755        -0.5212248        -0.5310275        -0.5351072        -0.5378716
```

So end result for example for first 2 rows would look like below. What is best method to do this without having to rbind multiple days (500 in my case)?

```
rbind(NSrates(para[1,], matu[1,]), NSrates(para[2,], matu[2,]))
           X1.15342465753425 X1.43013698630137 X1.65753424657534 X1.79452054794521 X1.92876712328767
2016-05-09        -0.5036755        -0.5212248        -0.5310275        -0.5351072        -0.5378716
2016-05-10        -0.5071923        -0.5195874        -0.5260411        -0.5284441        -0.5297903
```

And here is Data:

```
> dput(para)
structure(c(1.24225078418646, 1.31008637078059, 1.30543299665979, 
1.29631631535762, 1.29601365243175, -1.58742842487855, -1.69826559638279, 
-1.7093729214809, -1.64748723193503, -1.7037710977632, -2.87798606181918, 
-2.77191996754914, -2.74192263452223, -2.917838377094, -2.71618708784827, 
0.326043563651773, 0.298877004832293, 0.298877004832293, 0.326043563651773, 
0.298877004832293), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), na.action = structure(1:34, class = "omit", index = c(978307200, 
978393600, 978480000, 978566400, 978652800, 978912000, 978998400, 
979084800, 979171200, 979257600, 979516800, 979603200, 979689600, 
979776000, 979862400, 980121600, 980208000, 980294400, 980380800, 
980467200, 980726400, 980812800, 980899200, 980985600, 981072000, 
981331200, 981417600, 981504000, 981590400, 981676800, 981936000, 
982022400, 982108800, 982195200)), index = structure(c(1462752000, 
1462838400, 1462924800, 1463011200, 1463097600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(5L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("beta_0", "beta_1", "beta_2", "lambda"
)))


> dput(matu)
structure(c(1.15342465753425, 1.15068493150685, 1.14794520547945, 
1.14520547945205, 1.14246575342466, 1.43013698630137, 1.42739726027397, 
1.42465753424658, 1.42191780821918, 1.41917808219178, 1.65753424657534, 
1.65479452054795, 1.65205479452055, 1.64931506849315, 1.64657534246575, 
1.79452054794521, 1.79178082191781, 1.78904109589041, 1.78630136986301, 
1.78356164383562, 1.92876712328767, 1.92602739726027, 1.92328767123288, 
1.92054794520548, 1.91780821917808), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(1462752000, 1462838400, 1462924800, 
1463011200, 1463097600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("DBR 4 1/4 07/04/17", "OBL 0 1/2 10/13/17", 
"DBR 4 01/04/18", "OBL 0 1/2 02/23/18", "OBL 0 1/4 04/13/18")))
```

Comment: One method would be to pre-allocate a matrix of the correct size and then fill it in. `resultsMat <- matrix(0, 500, 5)`. Put the data in it and make the row names the dates.

Comment: is it possible to show in example? My R skills are not too robust yet. I added Data, as I forgot to dput it.